# How to repeat each dataframe row n number of times (n is different for each row)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'data' and a dictionary 'dict_repeat' which specifies how many times to repeat a row. For example, rows containing name 'Jack' should be repeated 3 times in 'data':

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Anna', 'Nick', 'Jack'],
        'Age': [19, 21, 19]}

dict_repeat = {
    'Anna': 1,
    'Nick': 2,
    'Jack': 3,
}
```

Initial data:

```
   Name  Age
0  Anna   19
1  Nick   21
2  Jack   19
```

Desired output:

```
   Name  Age
0  Anna   19
1  Nick   21
1  Nick   21
2  Jack   19
2  Jack   19
2  Jack   19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Name'].map(dict_repeat))]
```

output:

```
   Name  Age
0  Anna   19
1  Nick   21
1  Nick   21
2  Jack   19
2  Jack   19
2  Jack   19
```